# Post a link to Facebook Timeline using Parse

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, facebook

I am using Parse mobile platform to post a feed on facebook timeline. This is what they said in their docs : `Note that if you already have the Facebook SDK installed in your app, our version of the Facebook SDK will happily work alongside it.`

Take a look [here](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#fbusers-instance).
`The Parse SDK includes the entire Facebook SDK. All the classes are namespaced with PF_ to avoid conflicts with existing libraries. So, for example, the main Facebook object class in our SDK is PF_Facebook.`

This one works perfectly using [Facebook SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/publish-to-feed-ios-sdk/) :

```
- (IBAction)postFacebook:(UIButton *)sender {    
    self.postParams =
    [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:
     @"https://developers.facebook.com/ios", @"link",
     @"https://developers.facebook.com/attachment/iossdk_logo.png", @"picture",
     @"Facebook SDK for iOS", @"name",
     @"Here we go", @"message",
     @"Build great social apps and get more installs.", @"caption",
     @"The Facebook SDK for iOS makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated iOS apps.", @"description",
     nil];

    [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:self.postParams HTTPMethod:@"POST"
     completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
        [self showAlert:@"Link is posted" result:result error:error];
     }];
}
```

But when I use PF_FBRequestConnection, it does not work:

```
[PF_FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"
        completionHandler:^(PF_FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            [self showAlert:@"Link is posted" result:result error:error];
    }];
```

The error in the console:

```
Error: HTTP status code: 403
```

The thing is I could post a `photo or Status` using Parse, but not a link as you see.

I appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the version of `Parse` framework that I was using. You can check it out [here](https://www.parse.com/questions/fblogin-do-we-need-to-use-fbsessionactivesession-handledidbecomeactive) also.

For example this one did not supported on that version (1.1.12) :

```
[PF_FBSession.activeSession handleDidBecomeActive];
```

In the new version (1.1.13) problem is solved. So I could have this method:

```
// Convenience method to perform some action that requires the "publish_actions" permissions.
- (void) performPublishAction:(void (^)(void)) action {
    // we defer request for permission to post to the moment of post, then we check for the permission
    if ([PF_FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_actions"] == NSNotFound) {
        // if we don't already have the permission, then we request it now
        [PF_FBSession.activeSession reauthorizeWithPublishPermissions:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"publish_actions"]
            defaultAudience:FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends completionHandler:^(PF_FBSession *session, NSError *error) {
                if (!error) {
                    action();
                }
            //For this example, ignore errors (such as if user cancels).
        }];
    } else {
        action();
    }
}
```

And use it in this way:

```
[self performPublishAction:^{
        [PF_FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/feed" parameters:self.postParams HTTPMethod:@"POST"
            completionHandler:^(PF_FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                [self showAlert:@"Link is posted" result:result error:error];
        }];
    }];
```

Comment: I got an error "[0] (null) @"com.facebook.sdk:ErrorInnerErrorKey" : (no summary) "

Comment: And this "[1] (null) @"com.facebook.sdk:ErrorSessionKey" : (no summary) and "[2] (null) @"com.facebook.sdk:HTTPStatusCode" : (long)200"

Answer (score 0):

you has to check the permission your app has. From the [Facebook SDK documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/oauth/errors/)

**insufficient_scope:** The request requires higher privileges than provided by the access token. The resource server SHOULD respond with the HTTP 403 (Forbidden) status code and MAY include the "scope" attribute with the scope necessary to access the protected resource.